# VB not declaring variables

Tags: vb.net

I have declared the variable "array" but then it says that the variable is undeclared. Its not auto filling "array" when i type so i think that my project file is stuffed? Im in visual studio 2015 if that helps Any help would be great [Screen Shot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxtBv.png)

Comment: I doubt if this is VBA if you are using Visual Studio, so changed the tag to [vb.net]

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare variables/procedures at class level, but you cannot modify or execute anything there.

This is **invalid**:

```
Public Module Stuff
    Public array(147) As String 'VALID. Declarations can be performed at class level.
    array(0) = "Hello" 'INVALID. Modifications can not be performed at class level.
End Module
```

This is **valid**:

```
Public Module Stuff
    Public array(147) As String

    Public Sub FillArray()
        array(0) = "Hello"
    End Sub
End Module
```

You can however initialize the array with a set of values if you'd like:

```
Public Module Stuff
    Public array() As String = New String(147) {"Hello", "Item 1", "Blabla", ...} 'VALID.
End Module
```

And if you want to add loops and conditions to your initialization, ***and*** you're using Visual Basic 10.0 or above, you can use [**Lambda Expressions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions) to create an inline function:

```
Public Module Stuff
    Public array(147) As String = _
        Function()
            Dim Result(147) As String
            For x = 0 To Result.Length - 1
                Result(x) = "Item " & x
            Next
            Return Result
        End Function.Invoke()

End Module
```

Comment: Ok, cheers. You really saved me.

Answer (score 1):

`Array` is a reserved word in VBA.
try `Public arr(137) As String`

Comment: This isn't VBA. He's using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2015, and `Array` is a valid name there.

Comment: @Visual Vincent it was labled as VBA question

Comment: Yes, but it was edited before you posted the answer so I assumed since the answer was so short that you wouldn't have started it before the edit was made. Sorry. :)

Comment: @Visual Vincent my browser didn't refresh, sorry